# How do I get git init to work in my app's directory?

Tags: mac-osx, git, ruby-on-rails, terminal

I'm brand new to RoR and am following along a tutorial and am at this step http://railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#sec:git_setup but I can't `get git` init to work.

I **thought** I had Git installed per

```
   MacBook-Pro:~ capestany$ git --version 
   git version 1.7.3.1
```

But the only way I can get that to appear at all is by doing

```
  MacBook-Pro:~ capestany$ export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin/:$PATH
  MacBook-Pro:~ capestany$ git
```

I don't really know what I'm doing in terminal, are my paths or permissions wrong? Here's some more stuff when I echo the path:

```
  MacBook-Pro:~ capestany$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/git/bin/:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/libexec
```

Yes, I'm a newbie! So what do I need to do to get Git working in my Rails directories?

Comment: All the info is helpful, but how about showing us the output when you try and actually run `git init`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid exporting your PATH each time you want to use git, you can put it in your `.profile`

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin/:$PATH
```

Put this at the bottom of your `.profile` and each time you start up, you'll have git right away.

After you type `git init` in the folder where you want to start a repository, you should see

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /path/to/repo/.git/
```

If you `ls` the folder, you won't see anything because it is a hidden folder. Finder will not show you anything either. But typing `git status` will show that you are on the master branch and ready for your initial commit.